# Dependencies clash for pgf-umlsd

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am fairly new to latex and the way it compiles. I will try to explain my issue.

I want to draw Sequence Diagrams using Tikz with the help of pgf-umlsd. When I try to compile my document, I get the following error:

```
(C:\Users\LocalUser\Documents\project\report\myfile.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.42 \savepicturepage
                     {pgfid1}{7}
?
```

Which referes to the following line in the .aux file:

```
\savepicturepage{pgfid5}{7}
```

Here are the packages I declare to use in my document.

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{eurosym}

% use math packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

% TODOs package
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% After matter packages
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{natbib}

% Drawing diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
```

Surprisingly the `\savepicturepage` cannot be found. From where are the commands executed in the .aux file? How should I go to troubleshoot this issue? How could I see if there are dependencies clashes between the various packages?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a user-specific state of the TeX system which has been influenced by the previous actions.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the .aux file and compiling again solved the issue.